# How to use a custom codec for flash microphone strming over rtmp

Tags: flash, rtmp, red5

Currently I am building a conferencing application using flash and Red5. I have tried nellymoser and speex as codecs. But I am not satisfied with the results. I'd like to know weather there is any possiblity of using a codec like Opus or a custom codec with flash over rtmp protocol. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you unsatisfied? Sound quality, latency? Why won't mp3/aac not work?

Comment: @szatmary The requirement is for camera and microphone conferences. Not for VOD. One issue is rtmp is over tcp and has head of blocking problem. Again rtmp based solutions for conferences induces feedback, noise etc... Another issue is it fails(poor sound quality may be due to the codec) when there are more than 10 participants in a room. However these happen when you use the standard flash solution. I am trying to use a difference codec to see if it solves(eg:opus).  Or may be a custom codec.

Comment: Hi, have you ever succeeded in this? Have you reuse one of the AUDIODATA tag value for your custom codec? I'm just interested in how to use OPUS with RTMP